# Error running accumulator server in Orion

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware

I'm trying to run the accumulator server of Orion in order to receive notifications.

I've downloaded "contextBroker-tests" package and after having all the permissions and being in the path, I get this error:

```
./accumulator-server.py 1028 /accumulate on

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./accumulator-server.py", line 38, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, request, Response
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Is it needed another requirement? I don't know what could be happening, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert, but it looks like you're missing the Flask module.

Follow instructions on how to install it from [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/installation/)

If you have pip you can simply:

```
sudo pip install Flask
```